# How do I pass contextual filters to a view via services

Tags: 7, views, services

I have a view that accepts a contextual filter in order to return the correct results. I'm using Services 3 and Drupal 7. I'm able to create an endpoint, and retrieve the view via services. But it seems like there is no way to pass the contextual filter, because services_views only has a retrieve method (which uses GET). Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how it can be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

pass your filter as follows:
yourendpoint?args[0]=value&args[1]=value

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

As long as the filters are exposed in the view, the fieldnames are available as contextual filters. For instance, expose NID in the filters list and you can do

```
GET /endpoint?nid=5
```

Comment: This solution works for exposed filter criteria.  To the best of my knowledge contextual filters do not work, but this is an outstanding workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This is an already answered question, but for others browsing here in the future, I would recommend using and taking a look at the documentation at [Services Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views).  It spells out how to pass contextual filters along with a bunch of other possible arguments, and it has a demo video and shows examples.

Comment: After doing further research, it appears the this is not possible without modification of services_views.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use multiple value in your contextual filter, I suggest doing the following :

- Create your Contextual filter (in my case : nid)
- Click on "Provide a default value" and set the type as PHP
  Contextual Filter expect a string with multiple value separated by a + or a comma.

`return str_replace("|", "+", $_GET['nid']);`

- In the "More" section, check "Allow multiple values".

Now when calling your service, provide your contextual filters that way : .../my_service?nid=1|2|3

Answer (score 2):

For those of you still having issues, ensure that when you add a Filter to the View, under the settings for the specified Field, there is a Filter identifier. This needs to be the argument passed into the querystring in the two formats listed on the Services Views documentation.

Comment: I was struggling on that, not intuitive at all since I imagined the title to be used as a filter key. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a contextual filter with Drupal Services by:
1) enabling the 'Views Contextual Filter Query' module (https://drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query)
2) passing the contextual filter through the URL as a querystring.

In the contextual filter, you will have to select 'WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE' -> 'Query Parameter from the URL.  You will then be able to add the parameter name which you will use in the URL.  This also allows you to use the + and | characters for selecting multiple filter criteria.